# DbProviderFactory CreateConnection Fails for System.Data.SqlClient

Tags: vb.net

Here is the code to test with. Create a new Form, add a button and put this code in the button.

```
    Dim dbf As Data.Common.DbProviderFactory
    '
    ' uncomment one of the below dbf = 
    '
    'this fails
    'dbf = Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient")
    'these work
    'dbf = Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.Odbc")
    'dbf = Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb")

    Dim conn As Data.Common.DbConnection
    conn = dbf.CreateConnection
```

The create connection **only fails for SqlClient.**  The error is

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
  Source=System.Data
  TypeName=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()
       at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory.CreateConnection()
       at WindowsApplication1.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\dewayne.basnett\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line 19
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FPreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at WindowsApplication1.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=Failed to read the configuration section for enclave providers. Make sure the section is correctly formatted in your application configuration file. Error Message: Configuration system failed to initialize
       Source=System.Data
       StackTrace:
            at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
       InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
            BareMessage=Configuration system failed to initialize
            HResult=-2146232062
            Line=0
            Message=Configuration system failed to initialize
            Source=System.Configuration
            StackTrace:
                 at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
                 at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigRemoved(InternalConfigEventArgs e)
                 at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(String configPath, BaseConfigurationRecord configRecord)
                 at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
                 at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
                 at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
                 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
            InnerException: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
                 BareMessage=Unrecognized configuration section userSettings.
                 Filename=C:\Users\dewayne.basnett\AppData\Local\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1.vshos_Url_odwpvb4iq0tpdwxwwhwkttkzifz10zja\1.0.0.0\user.config
                 HResult=-2146232062
                 Line=3
                 Message=Unrecognized configuration section userSettings. (C:\Users\dewayne.basnett\AppData\Local\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1.vshos_Url_odwpvb4iq0tpdwxwwhwkttkzifz10zja\1.0.0.0\user.config line 3)
                 Source=System.Configuration
                 StackTrace:
                      at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
                      at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
                      at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
                      at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(Object sender, InternalConfigEventArgs e)
                 InnerException:
```

EDIT: The config file is created by the IDE, but FWIW here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <userSettings>
        <WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings>
            <setting name="AutoIncrement" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
        </WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

App.config contents

```
    'FAILING 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    '<configuration>
    '    <startup>
    '        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    '    </startup>
    '</configuration>

    'WORKING
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    '<configuration>
    '    <configSections>
    '        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
    '            <section name="WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false"/>
    '        </sectionGroup>
    '    </configSections>
    '    <startup>
    '        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
    '    </startup>
    '    <userSettings>
    '        <WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings>
    '            <setting name="foo" serializeAs="String">
    '                <value/>
    '            </setting>
    '        </WindowsApplication1.My.MySettings>
    '    </userSettings>
    '</configuration>
```

Comment: It is possibly a bad config file.  Follow the inner exception tree in the exception details window.  Do you have a "Configuration system failed to initialize." exception.  If so, keep following the exception tree to identify the file.  It may be an old file left over from something.  Try renaming the file with a new extension and try your application again.

Comment: No.  There is only the app config for new projects, and  it is minimal.

Comment: I did not scan down your post far enough originally, but it is showing an issue with: `C:\Users\dewayne.basnett\AppData\Local\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1.vshos_Url_odwpvb4iq0tpdwxwwhwkttkzifz10zja\1.0.0.0\user.config`.

Comment: I edited the post and added the contents of the config file.

Comment: So on a lark I added a setting to the projects 'Settings'.  Now it works.  As a double check I repeated the steps.  Without adding a setting it failed, with it all is good.  I'll edit the post above to show the before and after App.config.

Comment: Have you attempted my suggestion to rename the file at the path above?  An alternative is to rename the assembly (Project Menu->Proj Name Properties->Application Tab->Assembly name box.

Comment: Every time I created a new forms project the file path changed.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, and I am not sure of the mechanics behind this, is...

Yesterday a user in another domain was trying to install one of my apps and setup was throwing an error.  It looked like a permission problem but they insisted it was not. One of their programmers suggested that I change the properties of a code file from Do not copy to Copy always. I didn't think it would help, but they insisted.  Eventually I figured out that it was how they were mapping to the install directory.

They had it as \fileserver.mo.gov\install.  Changing it to \fileserver\install fixed the problem.  I did not change the code file back.

As this problem became more bizarre I thought of what happened yesterday and remembered the change.  I set it back to Do not copy, republished the app, and the above problem went away.  As I said I don't understand the mechanics behind this, but my issue is resolved.